# AutoScrollPosition does not report the correct value after setting it to a point location

Tags: c#, user-controls, scroll

I have a user control, which is scrollable control, and I want to change its `AutoScrollPosition` (only the X value).

I'm doing it like this:

```
int newScrollX = myFunction();
Point p = new Point(newScrollX, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
this.AutoScrollPosition = p;
```

newScrollX gets the correct value, p gets the correct point, but after the line of AutoScrollPosition setting, the AutoScrollPosition is (0,0).

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of newScrollX?  AutoScrollPosition is a bit odd: You have to pass it a positive value but it will report a negative value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AutoScrollPosition is quite cumbersome.

usually you get negative values when doing this:

```
Point p = this.AutoScrollPosition;
```

but when setting the scroll position you have to use positive values... so to restore the exact same scroll position you have to invert the negative numbers:

```
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-p.X, -p.Y)
```

Otherwise the AutoScrollPosition will be 0,0 as observed.

Comment: this is not just "cumbersome", it's counter-intuitive. But thanks for this answer, very helpful

Comment: this is not just "counter-intuitive", it's wrong :o) AutoScrollPosition is a property. If you set it it should not then return something different. If you set negative values then it changes them to 0. But if you set positive values it returns them as negatives. The setting should therefore be a method and the getting a read-only property. If I had an object Car and set the Colour property to Green and then the Colour property immediately returned Red I think we'd agree this is a very poorly designed class