# How to move the slider AutoScroll (button)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to move the slider in parts, exactly 200 points, right and left, if the entire length is exactly 600 points? Using the ButtonLeft and ButtonRight buttons...

[image: two muppets]

[image: two muppets]

[image: two muppets]

[image: two muppets]

```
    private void buttonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-200, 0);
    }

    private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(+200, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сorrect me if there is an error, but the code works: [SL#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301827/7549532) [SL#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081914/7549532)

```
    private void buttonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X - 200);
    }

    private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X + 200);
    }
```

or

```
    private void buttonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-p.X - 200)
    }

    private void buttonRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = panel1.AutoScrollPosition;
        panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-p.X + 200)
    }
```